# How can a PostgreSQL standby decide whether its primary is still active or not

Tags: postgresql

I have a setup with asynchronous streaming replication so that PSQL1 is primary and PSQL2 is hot standby.
Since PSQL2 is running in hot standby mode I can do run queries against it.

Is it possible on PSQL2 to tell whether PSQL1 is still active or already shutdown?
I tried `select pg_is_in_recovery();` but it returns true regardless whether PSQL1 is running or not.

Comment: Be warned that that would *not* be a good way to determine if you should fail over. That is way more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For streaming replication, you can check the [pg_stat_wal_receiver](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-WAL-RECEIVER-VIEW) view. There will be one line here when `wal receiver` is streaming.

Another question is why you need such information. For monitoring purposes, the amount of replication delay is much more important. Async replica may be significant lagged, but primary and `wal receiver` still alive (e.g. while reach the network bandwidth limit). Usually on hot standby:

```
select now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp();
```

and [`pg_stat_replication`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-REPLICATION-VIEW) on primary.

Comment: Thank's - this is exactly what I'am looking for. pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp() is a good hint too. However I discovered that now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp() can yield a negative interval in case the replay happens just when the query is executed. Therefore I changed it to 
`select -(pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp() - now())`